# MySql error 1064, cannot add columns. Syntax error

Tags: mysql

I know this has been asked before but none of the previous answers answer my question. In the mysql console I attempt to add a column called date to a table called Stocks using the following: `ALTER TABLE Stocks; ADD date date;` and it returns this:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD Date date' at line 1`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong! (Apologies if this is a dumb question, I started MySql yesterday)

Comment: Remove the `;` before `ADD`.  It is one single statement: `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD  newcolumn DATATYPE`

Comment: I did that and got the same error.

Comment: Making that change would not result in the same error. If you got another 1064, look closely at the end of it "right syntax to use near..."

Comment: ^^ That sounds like you omitted the keyword `TABLE`.

Comment: That is somewhat embarrassing.... my appologies

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ALTER TABLE Stocks ADD `date` date;
```

Or change column name